# Gentelella Combo Box

Tags: codeigniter, gentelella

I am using combo box - select custom, using gentelella template. On example , gentelella select custom, we can type text on the combo box and the list on the combo box will change accordingly to the text we type.

But In my case, I can not type the text on the combo box. It won't work.

## this is my view

```
<div class="item form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">NIK</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
                                            <option></option>
                                            <?php foreach ($listkary as $key => $value) { ?>
                                                <option value="<? echo $value['idnik']?>"><? echo $value['kodenik']?> - <? echo $value['namakary']?></option>
                                            <? } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: have you included the select2.js and select2.css files, also you will need to implement `<script>$(document).ready(function () { $('.select2_single').select2(); }); </script>` to make sure it is initialised. I had to do this last night on a project i've been working on so I know it def works. Good luck :)

Comment: hi mic, thanks. can you tell me where to put command  <script>$(document).ready(function () { $('.select2_single').select2(); }); </script> ? I am  new to webapps , i am totally blank. I already include selec2.js and select.css but no change. so I have to implement  <script>$(document).ready(function () { $('.select2_single').select2(); }); </script> but i don't know where to put it. Please help. thanks

Comment: just add it at the bottom of the view or in a js file

Comment: hi mic, thank you very much for your help. it work now.

Comment: Not a problem glad I could help